# Is the following arithmetic on conjugation of a set correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am given a set $H$ subset of a group $G$ closed under the binary operation and satisfying that if $g \in G$ then $g^2 \in H$. And I am to prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and that $G/H$ is Abelian.

What I have done is:

Take an an arbitrary $g \in G$.

We were told that for all $g \in G$, $g^2 \in H$ so $(gHg^{-1})^2 \subseteq H$

However $(gHg^{-1})^2 = gHg^{-1}gHg^{-1} = gH^2g^{-1} = gHg^{-1}$

I am not sure if my argument above is correct because I am not sure if my approach is mathematically correct.

Comment: I believe your proof is correct. Do you know how to prove that $G/H$ is abelian?

Comment: Show that $g_1Hg_2H = g_2Hg_1H$? :P algebra is not my strength

Comment: Here's a more general fact that may be easier to think about. Prove that any group with exponent 2, i.e. for which $g^2=e$ for all $g\in G$, is abelian. Also show that $G/H$ is such a group.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get $(gHg^{-1})^{2}\subset H$, because an arbitrary element of $A^{2}$ is $ab$ where $a,b\in A$. Also, you should prove $H$ is a subgroup first, that is, prove $H$ is closed under taking inverses and $H\neq \emptyset$. And then prove it is normal.

Comment: $H$ is closed under the binary operation, so $H^2 \subseteq H$ and as a matter of fact since $I^2 = I$ the identity is in $H$ as well.

So (gHg^{-1})^2 is just a lot of square elements all of which are, by definition, in $H$  

The worry si whetehr I can word my argument using the arithmetic I used

Comment: @Makogan So a general element in $(gHg^{-1})^{2}$ is $ghg^{-1}gh'g^{-1}=ghh'g^{-1}$ for some $h,h'\in H$. Why is it in $H$?

Comment: @Makogan, if $h\in H$, does $h^{-1}\in H$?

Comment: @ClémentGuérin yes, it's very easy to prove

Comment: @Makogan, how do you prove it? (I am genuinely asking the question)

Comment: Assume $h \in H$, ($h^{-2}$) is in $H$ by the property we described, and since the set is closed we get that $hh^{-2} = h^{-1}  \in H$

Comment: @Makogan can you explain how $(gHg^{-1})^2$ is just a lot of square elements?

Comment: Indeed I can it's called sucking at algebra

Answer (score 2):

Like highlighted in Delong's answer $(gHg^{-1})^2\subseteq H$ does not follow directly from the fact that $g^2\in H$ for all $g\in G$, because the most general element of $(gHg^{-1})^2$ is not a square but it is element of the form $gh_1h_2g^{-1}$ where $h_1,h_2$ are two elements of $H$.

Proving that $H$ is a group has already been dealt with.

Hint : $gHg^{-1}=H$ is equivalent to $gH=Hg$. Try to write any element $gh$ where $h\in H$ as some squares and elements of $H$ with a $g$ at the end.

> $gh=ghghh^{-1}g^{-1}=\underbrace{(gh)^2h^{-1}(g^{-1})^2}_{\in H}g$

For the remaining part (abelianity of $G/H$) Jalex Stark's comment is the good path. The hypothesis tells you that $G/H$ is of exponent $2$ or $1$ and any group of this kind needs to be abelian.

Comment: Look at delong's answer I provide the proof for closure under inverse in a comment

Comment: @Makogan, Thanks! It is indeed a piece of cake.  I edit my answer.